# How do I look up the current context in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Let's say I'm in VSCode (e.g. in the screenshot below in a [**Python** interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)), I'd like to define keybindings that **only** apply to a specific window type (e.g. Window 1, 2 or 3 in the screenshot below, which are window types for Python interactive development)

How can I look up the **current context** when the cursor is **focused** on any of them, so that I can use that in a `when` clause in my `keybindings.json`?

[image]

Note that in the example above, these are **Python-extension-specific** window types, namely:

- Python interactive window
- Plot Viewer
- Variable explorer and data viewer
- etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Developer: Inspect context keys` commands. This command lets you click on an UI element to print the context keys for it to the developer console.

[image: Inspect the terminal context]

You can view the output using `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`

[image: Context keys printed in the developer console]

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically obtain these values? Curious if they can be embedded within a string placed in package.json like "${context:my.variable}", or if I can do something like vscode.getContext('my.variable').